# Legendre symbol in the Fibonacci primality test

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers, primality-test, legendre-symbol

The Legendre symbol $\left(\dfrac{5}{p}\right)$ is used in the Fibonacci primality test. I understand its significance, but why did 5 show up and not some other prime? Is it because $p$ is written in base-10 or is it due to some property of Fibonacci/Lucas numbers?

Comment: Because a square root of $5$ is what you need for the [formula of the Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression).

Comment: The golden ratio is $\frac {1+\sqrt 5}2$, so there is a difference if $5$ is a quadratic residue.

Comment: The defining relation $f_{n+2}-f_{n+1}-f_n=0$ leads to the characteristic equation $x^2-x-1=0$, which has discriminant five.

Comment: Have the comments been helpful, Hrish?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP has lost interest.

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic equation of the Fibonacci sequence is $x^2 - Px + Q = 0 $ with $P = 1$ and $Q = -1$. The discriminant is
$D = P^2 - 4Q = 5$ and the roots are $ a = \frac{P+\sqrt{D}}2 = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2\quad\text{and}\quad b = \frac{P-\sqrt{D}}2 = \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}2$.

The terms of the Fibonacci sequence can be expressed in terms of the roots $a$ and $b$ as follows

$ F_n = \frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b} = \frac{a^n-b^n}{ \sqrt{D}} = \frac{a^n-b^n}{ \sqrt{5}} $.

So the $5$ in the Jacobi symbol is not being used because it is a prime but it is derived of the mentioned parameters $P$ and $Q$. For $P = 2, Q = -1$ (Pell sequence) it is $D = 8$; that sequence can also be used for primality testing.

For primality testing the [Jacobi symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol) - a generalisation of the Legendre symbol - is being used because it is valid for odd numbers and not only for
primes. Normally you do not now if $n$ is prime before you do a primality test.